# Behavior of SQL HAVING clause with aliased expressions - standards

Tags: postgresql, standards, impala

In Impala 3.0 SQL engine, the devs changed the behavior of GROUP BY, HAVING, and ORDER BY to allegedly be more conformant to the standards thus breaking Impala 2.x code.

For example, `select c,count(*) as n group by c having n>10 order by n desc;` is no longer allowed. The problem being `n>10`. The justification of it confirming to SQL standards. However, if one reads the comments in the jira ticket, the research solely consisted of comparing it to Postgres, Oracle, and other database engines. Even their comments showed that those other engines are not consistent.

Here's my question: Does the SQL92 or newer standard actually prohibit using named aliases in that way?

When I read through the standard I do not see such a prohibition. Reading the BNF grammar, it looks to me to be allowed.

For more information:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5191

[image: Inconsistent engines]

Comment: The standard contains this sentence regarding the having clause: "*Each column reference directly contained in the <search condition> shall be one of the following:
a) An unambiguous reference to a column that is functionally dependent on G.
b) An outer reference.*" Neither a "a reference to a column" nor an "outer reference" include a column alias as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "those other engines are not consistent". Neither Postgres, nor Oracle nor SQL Server allow that syntax.

Comment: Interestingly, the Impala devs allow column aliases to be used plainly but not in expressions! So HAVING n is allowed if n is Boolean...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: MySQL allows using aliases in the `HAVING` clause, but this is clearly [documented as an extension to the stanard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html): *Another MySQL extension to standard SQL permits references in the HAVING clause to aliased expressions in the select list.*